# How to identify three types of objects in a image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, classification

I want to identify three different objects from a satellite wind image. The problem is three of them are somewhat similar. I tried to identify using templete matching but it didn't work. Three objects are as follows.

[image: object 1]

[image: object 2]

[image: object 3]

Here the direction of the object is not important but the type of the head in the line is important. Can you suggest a way to proceed?

Comment: "I tried something and it did not work" is a little too broad of an error description as a starting point.

Comment: In template matching I gave this type of images as  templates and could identify only few objects ( two or three.) I want to identify the objects from around 100 objects spread cross an image.

Comment: Template matching does not do well with size variation or rotation. There is a chance that it is working on your image, though. cv2.MatchTemplate returns an array nearly the size of the image (image height - template height, image width -template width) with a score at each array element. So if you are searching for multiple instances of your template inside the image, you have to inspect the cv2.MatchTemplate results yourself. minMaxLoc will effectively only give you one match. [keypoint + homography](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html) is good alternate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image consists of only pure black and pure white pixels,

You can find contours and its  bounding rectangle or minAreaRect for each of them.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect

Then iterate over the contours considering there rectangles as separate images. Now you do classification of these images. You may use template matching too.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about machine learning?

for example a small cnn that is used for digits recognition could be "retrained" using a small set of your images, Keras also has an data augmentation feature to help ensure a robust classifier is trained.

There is a very good blog post by 
Yash Katariya found @ https://yashk2810.github.io/Applying-Convolutional-Neural-Network-on-the-MNIST-dataset/, in which the MNIST data set is loaded in and the network is trained, it goes through all of the stages you'd need to in order to use ML for your problem.

You mention you've tried template matching, however you also mention that the rotation is not important, which to me implies that an object could be rotated, that would cause failures for TM.

You could look into LBP (Local Binary Patterns), or maybe OpenCV's Haar Classifier (however it's sensitive to rotation).

Other than the items I have suggested there is a great tutorial found @ https://gogul09.github.io/software/image-classification-python which uses features and machine learning you may benefit from looking at to apply to this problem.

I hope while not actually giving you an answer to your question directly, I have given you a set of tools you can use that will solve it with some time invested and some reading.